# Arel time conversion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, arel

Time.now
 => Thu Nov 10 **15**:33:48 +0100 2011

Contract.where("date_end >= ?", Time.now)
=> [..] WHERE (date_end >= '2011-11-10 **14**:33:59') ORDER BY date_start ASC

how do you explain arel doesn't use the same timezone (an hour or difference) ?

in my application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Paris'

...but it's the same whatever i set ('UTC', etc..)

Thanks !

Comment: This is because your database timezone is set to UTC. Database defaults the timezone from the system. Your server timezone might be set to UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Because Arel doesn't know about your `config.time_zone` setting in your rails application. Arel only cares and deals with generating SQL strings.

And your example has nothing to do with Arel but rather with Rails. As pointed out in the comments I suspect your DB is set to UTC, so rails magically will convert your `Time.now` to UTC since all DateTime's saved in the DB are stored in UTC